# Reinstall MacOS Catalina on Macbook Air after failed Updates

Tags: macos, macbook-air, macos-catalina

I have a 2015 Macbook Air. My computer was trying to install the latest patch for Catalina, until when it just got hung up.

I tried rebooting but it just hangs up on the progress bar. I tried resetting the NVRAM and this time it completed the progress bar but still does not boot into OS.

I was wondering if I could reinstall MacOS Catalina on my MacBook Air. Since I cannot use my MacBook Air, I have a Windows PC.

Please guide me to download the official ISO from apples website and to install the OS on my MacBook Air.

Comment: There is no official way to download macOS from anything other than a Mac. Start the Mac from Recovery Cmd/R  or Internet Recovery Cmd/opt/R at boot & install from there. Or see https://superuser.com/questions/1493755/catalina-bricked-my-macbook-pro

Comment: Thanks, I ran the auto recovery and was able to reinstall MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Ran the Auto Recovery mode CMD + R. Followed the on screen instructions. Chose to reinstall MacOS. The recovery wizard automatically downloaded the necessary files for installation. Successfully reinstalled MacOS Catalina.

Note: For me the basic Auto Recovery worked just fine. For some users if this doesn't work then as suggested by @Tetsujin in the comment section of the question, please try Auto Recovery with Internet. If your internet connection to the ISP is via PPPOE, then it won't work. This is by design from Apple Inc.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't get to the App Store from the Recovery mode, try Internet recover, which will downgrade your computer, and then upgrade to El Captain, from there you can go to Catalina.
Alternatively you can find the official download for El Captain dmg here (Step 4) https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886

Comment: Cmd/R will re-install the 'current' OS from the existing Recovery Partition [that may be pooched if it failed at upgrade], or over the internet,  Cmd/opt/R will install the latest OS the machine is capable of running. Cmd/opt/shift/R will install the original OS that came with the Mac. El Cap is not needed at all, nor will it be easy to get without a working Mac. It would also guarantee to lose all existing data.

Comment: When I ran the auto recovery it also downloaded files from the internet. It worked fine for me.